# Standing desk sway stabilization

Tags: structural-engineering, vibration

I have a standing desk that sways when I'm typing and it is in the standing position. I've read numerous things online about this and can't find any actionable information for stabilizing the desk. It is only swaying back-and-forth, it is not swaying side-to-side. It is on casters and on carpet. I can maybe remove the casters, but I can't change the carpet.

I was thinking about tall buildings, like the 101 building in Taipei. That building has a mass damper that looks like a pendulum for wind loads and for earthquake damping. I figure my desk is basically suffering from the physics equivalent of that.

Would attaching a pendulum to my desk help counteract the motion? Are there considerations? What kind of weight should I start with, at what length? Should it be center-mounted along the longitudinal axis, both axis, or should it be offset somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It would be much simpler to just add mass to the underside of the desk. Increase its inertia so that you move (rather than the table) due to its reaction!

(From memory) aluminium has a density of about 3 kg/1000 cm<sup>3</sup>, steel about 7, lead about 10, mercury 13 and gold is particularly compact at 19 if you have 20 kg or so of it knocking about.

Comment: Test the theory by adding a lot of books, bricks, bags of flours, exercise weights, etc to rest on the top of the desk to see how much weight is actually needed.

Comment: Congrats on breaking 10,000. I had the honor of giving the final vote needed.

Comment: @RC_23, thanks! I wasn't counting. Most of my work has been done on Electronics.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking, adding mass directly to the bottom of the desk would be a pendulum with no length :P I have attachment points, so I can just as easily put it at the end of a cable. Would that potentially work better? I imagine that the answer will be: try and see :)